# Do I need a routing module for every url segment?

Tags: angular

New to angular and having problems understanding how many routing modules I'll need. I'm building a multi-level side navigation. Right now I only have 1 module besides the *app.module*. Here's the routing info for this lazy loaded *MyConfiguration* module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MyConfigurationComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'a',
        component: AComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'b',
        component: BComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'c',
        component: CComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '1',
            component: OneComponent
          },
          {
            path: '2',
            component: TwoComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

If I want the url to update to *my-configuration/c/1* when I select *OneComponent* does this mean that I need a new module + routing module for it?

I lazy load it from *app-routing.module*:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: homeComponent },
  {
    path: 'my-configuration',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./my-configuration.module').then(
        p => p.MyConfigurationModule
      )
  },
];
```

I want my url to update when I select *OneComponent* to this:

```
'my-configuration/c/1'
```

But, it errors:

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'my-configuration/1'
```

Because the activated route is *my-configuration*.

Here's the handler for clicking a link:

```
this.router
  .navigate([this.optionSelected.code], { relativeTo: this.route })
  .then(e => {
    if (e) {
      console.log('Navigation is successful!');
    } else {
      console.log('Navigation has failed!');
    }
  });
```

Does this mean that I need a new module + routing module? Something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'my-configuration',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./my-configuration/my-configuration.module').then(
        p => p.MyConfigurationModule
      )
  },
];
```

Comment: Your question lacks key information. For example *how do you access the child*? Because the error there is correct.

Comment: paths A and B do not have children. I expect this works with C path?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

**Note**: You need to conditionally append "../" only if you are accessing child routes of 'c'.

```
this.router
  .navigate(['../' + this.optionSelected.code], { relativeTo: this.route })
  .then(e => {
    if (e) {
      console.log('Navigation is successful!');
    } else {
      console.log('Navigation has failed!');
    }
  });
```

Comment: That was a typo, I am using "c". I'll update the post and add more info.

Comment: This doesn't work. It fails when I access the "c" component: my-configuration/..c

Comment: You need to conditionally append "../" only if you are accessing child routes of 'c'.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. I just have to figure out the best way to determine if it is a child.